# Analytic Functions and C-R equations

Tags: complex-analysis

Pls I need help on the following:
1). Show that $f(z)=i(x^{3}+c)$ is analytic
2). Prove that the fuction $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ is differentiable for all $z$ except at $z=0$ by using the Cauchy-Riemann equation.
3). Find the real and imaginary part of $sin z$ for complex z.

In the first question, I know that a function $f(z)$ is analytic in a region if it is differentiable at all points of the region, but here above, am I to differentiate once to show that $f(z)$ is analytic since no region is given.
In the second question, I can do it, but where the problem lies is where I'll separate the real from the imaginary. I'll be glad if someone can point this out for me.
Concerning the third question, I've been trying to show it using exponentials but still again I can't separate the real from the imaginary.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Part 1 (I guess, you meant $f(z) = i \cdot(z^3+c)$): You know, that if $h$ and $g$ are analytic, then also $h\cdot g$ and $h+g$ are analytic. Use this to prove the homlomorphy of $f$ (Note that $f$ is a composition of constant functions and the identity function $id(z)=z$ which are analytic).

Part 2: $\frac 1{x+iy}=\frac x{x^2+y^2} - \frac y{x^2+y^2} i$ (why?). Check that $i(x,y)=\frac x{x^2+y^2} - \frac y{x^2+y^2} i$ fulfills the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Part 3: Use $\sin(x+iy)=\frac 1{2i}\left(e^{i(x+iy)}-e^{-i(x+iy)}\right)$ and $e^{x+iy}=e^x\left(\cos(x)+\sin(y)i\right)$ to get $\sin (x + iy) =\cosh y + i \cos x \sinh y$. Do the same as in part 2.